# Accessing control from another thread safely

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm creating a program that draws points in a bitmap in memory (using system.drawing) and displays it in a PictureBox control, this way :

```
private void button_startGen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    continueTask_generate = true;

    Task task = Task.Run(() => {
        while(continueTask_generate) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) {
                gm.GenerateNextPoint();
            }
            UpdateBitmap();
            Thread.Sleep(Time);
        }
    });
}

private void UpdateBitmap() {
    pictureBox_bitmap.Image = gm.bitmap;
}
```

The way this works is that, when you press the button "start generation", it'll start generating points, and you'll see that generation in the PictureBox. It generates i points, and then updates the pictureBox, waits for t milliseconds, and does the process again, until you press a "stop" button.

Now, as I'm updating the pictureBox control from a different thread than the main one, I'll get those pesky "InvalidOperationException". I'm a noob in threading. I've tried both solutions in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls) but none of them worked for me.

(For reference, this is my 'updated' UpdateBitmap() method for the first solution, which it didn't work:
        private delegate void UpdateBitmapDelegate();

```
    private void UpdateBitmap() {
        if(pictureBox_bitmap.InvokeRequired) {
            UpdateBitmapDelegate deg = new UpdateBitmapDelegate(UpdateBitmap);
            pictureBox_bitmap.Invoke(deg);
        }
        else {
            pictureBox_bitmap.Image = gm.bitmap;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm making this program mainly to learn this kind of thing.

Edit:
I'm not sure if the content of gm.GenerateNextPoint() is relevant, but I'll post it too. GenerateNextPoint() calls this method:

```
    private void DrawPoint(Point point, int radius, Color color) {
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
                if (radius > 0 && radius < 3) {
                    g.FillRectangle(brush, point.X, point.Y, radius, radius);
                }
                else if (radius > 1) {
                    int radiusOffset = (int)(radius / 2f);
                    g.FillEllipse(brush, point.X - radiusOffset, point.Y - radiusOffset, radius, radius);
                }
            }
    }
```

This method also interacts with gm.bitmap, as does UpdateBitmap().

Comment: You are making us fill in too many blanks.  Document UpdateBitmapDelegate.  What's calling DrawPoint?  Your code example isn't a really good test case for threading, because drawing basically has to happen on the GUI thread anyway.  A timer would work better.  Background threads are better for calling data or downloading information from a server — long running operations, etc.

Comment: Not the solution I expected, but the implementation with Timer works wonders. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try this:

Add this to your function on the other thread-

```
                 if (InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    { //your working code here }));
                }
                 else
                {
                    //the same code here
                }
```

Comment: I'm nut sure if you meant adding that to the UpdateBitmap() method or in other place. I tried the former and it didn't work.

Comment: @Kaisadilla:   I surely mean adding it to the function **that runs on another thread**. If your UpdateBitmap() method runs on another thread, add it to that method. This code should work in all the functions which run on seperate threads and need to access controls on the main thread. Pls understand that these lines are important when performing cross-thread operations.**According to me , add this to every method that runs on a thread other than the main one.**

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting it right. I remade the Task [to just call a function doing its previous thing](https://i.imgur.com/k57gscZ.png), and that function implements your code. It "works" without threading errors, but it now freezes the form and thus cannot be stopped.

Comment: The way it's intended to work on my original post is: the form runs in its thread, and you have a class (gm) with a bitmap in memory.

You click "generate" (button_startGen_Click() method) in the form, and that creates a Task that will continuously do two things: first call GenerateNextPoint() in gm (a method that just adds a point to the bitmap), and then change a pictureBox in the form to contain this new version of the bitmap, then the task sleeps for x milliseconds and does the same again.

Comment: If I understood my problem correctly, this second thing (changing pictureBox.Image) should be done by the form thread, and not any other.

Comment: Anyway, as another person suggested, I used a timer instead of another thread, which I  can see why is a better solution for this specific problem. Thank you for your help, though. I've tested Tasks and threads for more simple problems (like just updating a label) and it does work in that case. I guess this problem is a bit too complex for my almost null experience with threads at the moment.

Comment: @Kaisadilla:   Exactly. Also, if you need to do it from another thread, you should add your code in the code provided by me in place of `//your working code here`. Accept this as the answer as this is helpful for cross-thread operations. It ca be helpful to others.